# JavaFX MenuItem does not react on MouseEvent.CLICKED

Tags: java, javafx

I am writting a little desktop application with a TreeView according to the Oracle-Example from here: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/tree-view.htm.

From a MenuItem action of a ContextMenu, I would like to fire an event which shall create a new TreeItem below the item where I opened the ContextMenu from.

For MenuItem, it is possible to use the `setOnAction(EventHandler<ActionEvent> event)` method, but I only want to fire the action from a left mouse-click.

First, it is not possible to add an EventHandler to a MenuItem although it provides the method `addEventHandler(EventType type, EventHandler<EventType> handler)` with the event-type MouseEvent.ANY (or anything else). The handle-method of the event-handler is not called.

Second, i can use a workarround by adding a Label to a MenuItem by `menuItem.setGraphic(label)` and add an EventHandler to the label. This one works although `MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED` is not called by an EventHandler's handle-method on a Label.

Is this "normal" behaviour? I understand that a label does not react on a click-event, but I do not understand why it is not possible to register a separate EventHandler or EventFilter on a MenuItem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ContextMenu` uses a `MenuItemContainer`, which is a

> Container responsible for laying out a single row in the menu - in other
>       words, this contains and lays out a single MenuItem, regardless of it's 
>       specific subtype.

Fur this purpose it seems to create new `Nodes` representing the `MenuItem`. So any `EventHandlers` added to the `MenuItem` will not be called.

To make it work as you intended, you can use a `CustomMenuItem` and add the according `EventHandler` to its `content`:

```
 public class ContextMenuCell extends TreeCell<String> {

        private ContextMenu menu;

        public ContextMenuCell() {
            Label lbl = new Label("Add item");
            MenuItem menuItem = new CustomMenuItem(lbl);

            lbl.setOnMouseClicked(evt -> {
                if (evt.getButton() != MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
                    return;
                }

                TreeItem treeItem =
                        new TreeItem<String>("New item");

                if (getTreeItem().isLeaf()) {
                    getTreeItem().getParent().getChildren().add(getIndex(), treeItem);
                } else {
                    getTreeItem().getChildren().add(0, treeItem);
                }

            });

            menu = new ContextMenu(menuItem);
        }

        @Override
        public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (empty) {
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                setText(item);
                setGraphic(getTreeItem().getGraphic());
                setContextMenu(menu);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your solution also works for me, thank you. It seems that the API is not 100% clear at this point because many of the controls in packackge javafx.scene.control can handle separate EventHandler's and EventFilter's.

Answer (score 0):

`Menu` and `MenuItem` are not `Nodes`, so they will not handle mouse clicks since they are not displayed on the screen. A workaround is to set a graphics object (`Node`) to the `MenuItem` and add the listener to this `Node`. Works also for other menus like CheckMenuItem etc.:

```
public class RunJavaFX extends Application {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    //the label will be our graphics object (Node)
    Label l = new Label("Your Menu Text");
    l.setTextFill(Color.BLACK); //set black since default CSS Style sets it to background color of the Menu
    //add either over addEventFilter or addEventHandler        
    l.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, ev -> {
                 if (ev.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
                     System.out.println("RightClick: " + ev.getSource() + System.nanoTime());                         
                 } else {
                     System.out.println("Not Right Click: " + ev.getSource() + System.nanoTime());
                 }
                 ev.consume(); //optional
             });
    //create the MenuItem with an empty text and set the label l as graphics object
    MenuItem mI = new MenuItem("", l);
    //create the dummy menu and MenuBar for the example
    Menu m = new Menu("Menu");        
    m.getItems().add(mI);
    MenuBar mB = new MenuBar(m);
    //create the dummy scene for the example
    Scene scene = new Scene(mB);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

}
```